# Java - Take any char one by one input from the Scanner

Tags: java

I want check all char one by one **without use ENTER** char. For example I put `foobar.`

and I check f, fo, foo, foob, fooba, foobar and foobar. and when I find a dot I exit program

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String phrase = null;
do{
   mychar = input...???;
   System.out.println(phrase);
} while(mychar!='.');
input.close();
```

Comment: I suggest that you google "java Scanner" and click on the first link to the documentation. It will describe all of the methods that are available.

Comment: Please let me know if the duplicate doesn't address your problem.